# How to download AWS S3 bucket PHP without specifying destination

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been following this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-transfer.html, but I'd like to be able to automatically download the bucket to a computer's download folder (maybe even tar.gz it). I tried not specifying a destination, but it is a mandatory parameter. Should I just traverse each instead, or is there a way to use AWS transfer manager for PHP in order to achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: Download all the files in the entire bucket?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to output it straight to the visitor

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILE.NAME"');

    $s3 = new S3($key, $secret);
    $s3->getObject("BUCKETNAME", "FILE.NAME", fopen("php://output", "wb"));

 ?>
```

Comment: No, sorry. I'm trying to download the file itself.